# Getting the last number in a series before lowering it below threshold in R

Tags: r, csv

I have the following data:

```
dat<- structure(list(Pentad = 1:73, RR = c(0, 0.014285714, 0, 0.088571429, 
0.071428571, 0, 0.065714286, 0.028571429, 0.094285714, 0.011428571, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.04, 0, 0.814285714, 0.285714286, 1.14, 5.334285714, 
2.351428571, 1.985714286, 1.494285714, 2.005714286, 20.04857143, 
25.00857143, 16.32, 11.06857143, 8.965714286, 3.985714286, 5.202857143, 
7.802857143, 4.451428571, 9.22, 32.04857143, 19.50571429, 3.148571429, 
2.434285714, 9.057142857, 28.70857143, 34.15142857, 33.02571429, 
46.50571429, 70.61714286, 3.168571429, 1.928571429, 7.031428571, 
0.902857143, 5.377142857, 11.35714286, 15.04571429, 11.66285714, 
21.24, 11.43714286, 11.69428571, 2.977142857, 4.337142857, 0.871428571, 
1.391428571, 0.871428571, 1.145714286, 2.317142857, 0.182857143, 
0.282857143, 0.348571429, 0, 0.345714286, 0.142857143, 0.18, 
4.894285714, 0.037142857), YY = c(0.577142857, 0, 1.282857143, 
1.445714286, 0.111428571, 0.36, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.011428571, 0.008571429, 
0.305714286, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.062857143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.013333333, 
0.043333333, 1.486666667, 0, 2.486666667, 1.943333333, 0.773333333, 
8.106666667, 7.733333333, 0.5, 4.356666667, 2.66, 6.626666667, 
4.404285714, 7.977142857, 12.94285714, 18.49428571, 7.357142857, 
11.08285714, 9.034285714, 14.29142857, 34.61428571, 45.30285714, 
6.66, 6.702857143, 5.962857143, 14.85428571, 2.1, 2.837142857, 
7.391428571, 32.03714286, 9.005714286, 3.525714286, 12.32, 2.32, 
7.994285714, 6.565714286, 4.771428571, 2.354285714, 0.005714286, 
2.508571429, 0.817142857, 2.885714286, 0.897142857, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.145714286, 0.434285714)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-73L))
```

There are three columns: Pentad, RR, and YY.

I would like to get the following:

(a) Get the first pentad when the precipitation exceeds the "annual mean" in "at least three consecutive pentads"

(b) Get the last pentad when the precipitation exceeds the "annual mean" in at least three consecutive pentads BEFORE lowering it below the annual mean.

I was able to do (a) using the following script:

```
first_exceed_seq <- function(x, thresh = mean(x), len = 3)
{
  # Logical vector, does x exceed the threshold
  exceed_thresh <- x > thresh

  # Indices of transition points; where exceed_thresh[i - 1] != exceed_thresh[i]
  transition <- which(diff(c(0, exceed_thresh)) != 0)

  # Reference index, grouping observations after each transition
  index <- vector("numeric", length(x))
  index[transition] <- 1
  index <- cumsum(index)

  # Break x into groups following the transitions
  exceed_list <- split(exceed_thresh, index)

  # Get the number of values exceeded in each index period
  num_exceed <- vapply(exceed_list, sum, numeric(1))

  # Get the starting index of the first sequence where more then len exceed thresh
  transition[as.numeric(names(which(num_exceed >= len))[1])]
  }

  first_exceed_seq(dat$RR)
```

Here's the plot of the time series:

[image: sample plot]

The correct answer in (a) is 27.

I would like to ask how can I do this for (b). The correct answer for (b) should be 57.

I'll appreciate any help on in this in R.

Comment: Just to be sure, RR is the precipitation and the annual mean is RR mean, correct?

Comment: Can't you do something like: `length(dat$RR) - first_exceed_seq(rev(dat$RR)) +1` ?

Comment: @MarcioRodrigues yes!!

Comment: @Mako OMG! yes!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got your problem right.

This is what I tried:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(
    anual_mean = mean(RR),
    exceed_thresh = RR > anual_mean,
    lag1 = lag(exceed_thresh, 1),
    lag2 = lag(exceed_thresh, 2),
    pick_3 = ifelse(exceed_thresh & lag1 & lag2, RR, NA)
  )
```